# Retrieving Case Object using Visual Studio Code and Salesforce CLI

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

Using Visual Studio Code and Salesforce CLI I am trying to retrieve "Case Object" details. But I was not able to fetch it. But the Account object is retrieved. Any particular reason? Did anyone face similar issues? I was not able to pull one custom object also similar way. This is happening in the sandbox. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same with below package.xml in my sandbox and i am able to get the metadata.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Case</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

See the screenshot:-

[image]

Please match your xml with mine and try once. let me know the results.

Comment: Thank You, Sanket! It worked.  But had a similar file, Not sure why it didn't work in the first place. Maybe some spelling mistakes. Will try the same for Custom Object and try it.